# Get highest value ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

I need to print the Region ID and the count of countries he holds, but only for the highest one.

My table is like this:

```css
COUNTRY_ID        COUNTRY_NAME     REGION_ID
AR                Argentina           2
AU                Belgium             3
BE                Brazil              1
BR                Canada              2
CA                Switzerland         2
CN                China               1
DE                Germany             3
```

And the result must be something like:

```css
REGION_ID      Quantity
   2              3
```

Comment: OK what have you tried?  Are you familiar with GROUP BY?  Read up on that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql for that purpose.
I use row_number analytic function to rank the rows after being grouped by REGION_ID column. Then, I filter by rnb = 1 to get the row with maximun quantity.

```sql
select REGION_ID, QUANTITY
from (
    select t.REGION_ID, count(*)quantity, row_number()over(order by count(*) desc) rnb
    from YourTable t
    group by t.REGION_ID
)
where rnb = 1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=221fa59b3d9d1dc6faa92cf18f1bce29)

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12c, you can use:

```sql
SELECT region_id,
       COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY region_id
ORDER BY quantity DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Before that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT REGION_ID,
         COUNT(*) AS quantity
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY region_id
  ORDER BY quantity DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME, REGION_ID) AS
SELECT 'AR', 'Argentina',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AU', 'Belgium',     3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BE', 'Brazil',      1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BR', 'Canada',      2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA', 'Switzerland', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CN', 'China',       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE', 'Germany',     3 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | REGION_ID | QUANTITY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28106e263d1f017bc912a750dc624b06)*

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you may nest aggregate functions to calculate total on `group by` result. So you may use [`last`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC) aggregate function to get highest id:

> ```
> select
>   max(region_id) keep(
>     dense_rank last
>     /*
>       region_id for highest count(*)
>       calculated per region_id
>     */
>     order by count(*) asc
>   ) as region_id,
>   max(count(*)) as quantity
> from table_name
> group by region_id
> ```
>
> ```
> REGION_ID | QUANTITY
> --------: | -------:
>         2 |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=596f610d1cb316d4abb7d85490104218)*